# Jhipster entity how to use it on page

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am learning some fullstack stuff. I created a JHipster project and created an entity called Post, in which i have a few fields like subject, body and name of author of the post. Model is working i can add new Posts. The thing is i wanna put entity on home page in a block like a Blog.
This is my homepage:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="hipster img-fluid rounded"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
       <h1>Welcome to JBlog!</h1>
        <div *ngFor="let post of posts">
            <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
            <p [innerHTML]="post.body"></p>
         <small>Written By: {{post.author}}</small>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {Post} from "app/shared/model/post.model";
import {PostService} from "app/entities/post/post.service";
import {ResponseWrapper} from "app/shared/model/response-wrapper.model";

@Component({
selector: 'jhi-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['home.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

posts: Post[] = [];

constructor(private postService: PostService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
 console.log("ngOnInit...")
 this.loadAll();
}

loadAll() {
 this.postService.query().subscribe(
   (res: ResponseWrapper) => {
     console.log(res.json);
     this.posts = res.json;
   },
   (res: ResponseWrapper) => {
     console.log(res.json);
   }
 );
}

}
```

function loadAll() is coppied from a tutorial which was a angular in version 4, mine is 9 and it not working. I added a class response-wrapper, but im not sure what i should put there, Could anyone tell me how to begin with such task? How the response should be looks like.
I'm pasting the response-wrapper but i know its invalid.

```
export class ResponseWrapper {
constructor(
 public headers: Headers,
 public json: any,
 public status: number
) { }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpResponse instead.

```
    loadAll(): void {
    this.postService.query().subscribe(
      (res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.posts = res.body;
      },
      (res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        // console.log(res);
      }
    );
  }
```